# Как правильно делать фильтры данных в Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, фильтры

Я получаю список данных по кино. У меня есть несколько полей:

1. Выбрать кино
2. Выбрать жанр
3. Выбрать актёров

Я делаю довольно банально. При выборе жанра заполняется массив.
При выборе кино вместо списка данных я получаю лишь 1 экземпляр соответственно.

Актёров я хочу выбирать из фильтрованного списка. Я сделал функцию, которая каждый раз из изначальных данных делает фильтрованные, но, получается, при фильтрации по актёрам я перезаписываю данные и не могу, к примеру, перевыбрать актёров или добавить новых. Я вижу только данные, которые отфильтровались.

Как правильно делают фильтры при таких ситуациях?